# Why is an inner class forced to implement its interface methods, even if the outer class has it?

Tags: java, interface, implementation, inner-classes, shadowing

```
public class Outer{
  public void sayHello(){ System.out.println("Hello!");}
  public class Inner implements HelloSayers{}
public interface HelloSayers{
  public void sayHello();
}
```

> The type Outer.Inner must implement the inherited abstract method HelloSayers.sayHello().

But the problem is the inner class should be considered as implementer of the outer methods. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are wrong.

`Inner` can *access* the members of `Outer`, but that does not mean it shares those members.

I.e. every instance of `Inner` contains a reference to the corresponding `Outer` object (`Outer.this`). If you access a member of `Outer` from `Inner` in your java code, the compiler just translates this to a access to the member of the `Outer` referenced by the `Inner` object. The `Inner` class does not contain those members.